# Cannot disable list in Sencha Touch

Tags: list, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, hide

I have a list in Sencha Touch and I want to disable the list when a button is clicked.  I am handling the "tap" event of the button.  However, when I run the line of code: `me.getWhatScreen().down('list[name=taskList]').disable();` the list does not disable.  I know I can hide the list, but I would rather just disable it (blur it).  Am I missing anything?  I have checked the Sencha docs.

Answer (score 1):

Better mask the whole list using this:

```
me.getWhatScreen().down('list[name=taskList]').mask();
```

It will add a shaded layer over the list. If you want it to be completely transparent, add some css on the mask element. You can remove the mask using unmask() method.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Calling the mask() method is actually not working for me. :( Any other ideas?

Comment: me.getWhatScreen().down('list[name=taskList]').setMasked(true); should work.

Comment: are you sure `me.getWhatScreen().down('list[name=taskList]')` is actually returning the required list? log it in console before adding mask to it.

Answer (score 0):

As for as what i understood if disable not working,

After clicking button just try setting list disableSelection config as true

```
 alist.setDisableSelection(true)
```

This configuration will lock the selection model of list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you can also find list id from inspecting elements.

```
Ext.getCmp('listid').disable();
```